# MS Excel range of values in cell between percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently using this function:

```
=IF(G5=80%,A32,IF(G5=85%,B32,IF(G5=90%,C32,IF(G5=95%,D32,IF(G5=100%,E32,IF(G5=101%,F32,IF(G5=102%,G32,IF(G5=103%,H32,IF(G5=104%,A33,IF(G5=105%,B33,IF(G5=106%,C33,IF(G5=107%,D33,IF(G5=108%,E33,IF(G5=109%,F33,IF(G5=110%,G33,)))))))))))))))
```

As you can see I've used specific numbers to match specific values only.
The issue I have is that if G5 is equal to 84% for example, I do not get the wanted value, which is 30%.

What Excel function should I use in my case? I believe I need to use some sort in the function, but I am not sure. For example, if G5 is between 80% and 85%, I should get 30% in H5.

If G5 is between 85% and 90%, I should get 35% in H5. Could you please provide me the exact syntax I need to use and the proper function for that?

Comment: Start with your highest and work backwards. =IF(g5>110%,'a',if(g5>105%,'b',if(g5>100%,'c'....

Answer (score 0):

Use CHOOSE/MATCH:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(G5,{0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.1}),A32,B32,C32,D32,E32,F32,G32,H32,A33,B33,C33,D33,E33,F33,G33)
```

MATCH returns the relative position to CHOOSE which then returns the correct value from the range.

But this would be easier if you created a lookup table:

[image]

Then just use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,N:O,2)
```

[image]